# How to fill in Cells by a multiple of cell value?

Tags: excel

noob Excel user here. I have a spreadsheet with a lot of cells filled. I am creating a table in the same spreadsheet, but want to pick out specific cells from the already filled cells.

For example, the already filled cells have:

```
  A B C D
1 # # # #
2 # # # #
3 # # # #
4 # # # #
5 # # # #
6 # # # #
```

In my new table, in column A, I want to include **every other** item from the already filled A above:

```
  A 
1 A2
2 A4 
3 A6
```

My question is: what is the quick way to do this? For example, let's say I have A2 filled above, but not A4 and A6. How can I just drag the A2 column down so that the pattern applies? Thanks for all the help.

Comment: Is there actually a pattern? Or do you need to be able to pick up arbitrary values from the original A2, A4, A6 cells? And are you tring to do this with VBA? Or manually?

Comment: The pattern would be: current new cell = previous cell address of old table + 2. I am just using excel, not VBA. Another way to think of what I want: normally, when you drag a current cell (the '+' mark) down, it will fill the following rows by the previous cell +1, but I want +2.

Comment: If your data is in sheet1 (from A1 down) and you put this in A1 of sheet2 you can fill down: `=INDIRECT("Sheet1!A" & ROW()*2)`

Comment: @TimWilliams: Nice...yours might be a bit more elegant than mine.
=)

Comment: What if I had my data in the same sheet? Could I do =INDIRECT("E27" & ROW()*2)?

Comment: You can do it anywhere, as long as you work out the math to end up with the correct cell address.

Comment: If you're having trouble debugging your formula then remove the INDIRECT() part and look at the addresses that get created.  When they look OK you can add back the INDIRECT().

Answer (score 1):

Ok...this might work...

```
  A B C D E
1 # # # # =A1
2 # # # # =A3
3 # # # # =A5
4 # # # # etc...
```

Your new table (these are functions)

```
  A
1 =INDIRECT(E1)
2 =INDIRECT(E2) 
3 =INDIRECT(E3)
4 =INDIRECT(E4)
```

Answer (score 0):

This could work as well:

In `B1` (or `C1`, or `D1`):

`=INDIRECT("A"&ROWS(1:$1)*2)`

Copy down